# Overidden delete is not called when compiled with clang 10 for visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, llvm-clang

I wrote some code to trace memory with an overridden `new` and `delete` operator:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;

auto operator new(size_t size) -> void* {
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    // std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes\n";
    printf("Allocating %zu bytes\n", size);
  }
  return malloc(size);
}

auto operator delete(void* p, size_t size) -> void {
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    // std::cout << "Freeing " << size << " bytes\n";
    printf("Freeing %zu bytes\n", size);
  }
  free(p);
}

class Object {
public:
  Object() = default;
  ~Object() = default;

private:
  int a_;
  int b_;
};

auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
  {
    auto* object = new Object();
    delete object;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I compile with `Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 Release - amd64` everything is ok and it prints:

```sh
Allocating 8 bytes
Freeing 8 bytes
```

But when I compile with `Clang 10.0.0 for MSVC with Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 Release (amd64)` then `delete` is not called:

```sh
Allocating 8 bytes
```

Why `clang` has this behaviour?

Comment: As per [operator delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete), it isn't specified if the `delete` will call `auto operator delete(void* p, size_t size) noexcept -> void` that you provided (although missing the `noexcept`), or `auto operator delete(void* p) noexcept -> void` (which is what it called for me).

Comment: @Eljay You mean this is not specified in Cpp standard?Then how can I trace the freed memory?

Comment: I'm not a language-lawyer, but I believe the C++ standard specifies that either operator delete(void*) or operator delete(void*, size_t) may be called.

Comment: @Eljay than you,I try override both of them tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer if anyone needs it.
As @Eljay said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031085/overidden-delete-is-not-called-when-compiled-with-clang-10-for-visual-studio-201#comment113227890_64031085), you need to override two versions the the `delete` operator

```cpp
auto operator delete(void* p, size_t size) -> void {
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    // std::cout << "Freeing " << size << " bytes\n";
    printf("Freeing %zu bytes\n", size);
  }
  free(p);
}

auto operator delete(void* p) -> void {
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    // std::cout << "Freeing " << size << " bytes\n";
    printf("Freeing unknow bytes\n");
  }
  free(p);
}
```